# Try to parsing json into class object fail

Tags: json, swift

I need help to parsing the json using Swift .  I could not parse them into an array of a class object using swift.  What I tried is I bundle the json key value into an array of object and return.  However, I could not deal with the types.  It so confuse.

Could someone help me.

The json I have:

```
{ 
 "mass_info1":
  [{
    "mass_id":7780, 
    "mass_date":"5/1/2019", 
    "mass_time":"7:30 PM", 
    "mass_location":"", 
    "mass_description": “Blah1” 
  } ] , 
 "mass_info2":
  [ { 
    "mass_id":7781, 
    "mass_date":"6/10/2019", 
    "mass_time":"7:30 PM", 
    "mass_location”:”1234 some place Los Angeles”, 
    "mass_description": “blah2” 
  } ] , 
 "mass_info3":
  [ { 
    "mass_id":7783, 
    "mass_date":"5/21/2019", 
    "mass_time":"7:30 PM", 
    "mass_location":"", 
    "mass_description": “blah3” 
  } ] , 
 "mass_info4":
  [ {
    "mass_id":1115, 
    "mass_date":"4/5/2019", 
    "mass_time":"2:30 PM", 
    "mass_location":"4050 Mission Ave, Oceanside, CA 92057", 
    "mass_description": “blah4”
  } ] 
}
```

> The class MassInfoObject import Foundation

```
struct MassInfoObject {
    var mass_id:Int
    var mass_date: String?
    var mass_time:String?
    var mass_location:String?
    var mass_description:String?
   init(mass_id:Int,mass_date:String,
   mass_time:String,mass_location:String,mass_description:String)
  {
        self.mass_id=mass_id
        self.mass_date=mass_date
        self.mass_time=mass_time
        self.mass_location=mass_location
        self.mass_description=mass_description   
    }
}
```

and the code that I get the json from a URLSession.

```
    func getjson()->[MassInfoObject]? {
            let urlPath = "http://myclassinfo.com/dev/json.php"
            let url = URL(string: urlPath)
            var massObjArray = [MassInfoObject]()
            var index:Int = 0
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
                print("Task completed")

                guard data != nil && error == nil else {
                    //print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                        for (key, value) in jsonResult {
                            //print("Value: \(value) for key: \(key)")
                            if let results = jsonResult[key] as? [String] 
      {

                                let dict = results[index].toJSON() as? [String:AnyObject] // can be any type here
                                for (key,value) in dict!{
                                    let result2 = dict![key] as! String
                                    print (result2)
                                }
                             }

                        }
                    }
                } catch let parseError as NSError {
                    print("JSON Error \(parseError.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }

            task.resume()
            return massObjArray
        }
```

Comment: Your JSON is organized very poorly. Why have a top-level dictionary where the values for each key are each an array with one dictionary in them? You should have an array at the top containing just the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json you are trying to parse does not have a very logical structure. If you have control over the json, you should work on that first. If you don't have control I suggest converting the json on your client end before parsing.

The following works in a Playground:

```
let str = """
{ "mass_info1": [{ "mass_id":7780, "mass_date":"5/1/2019", "mass_time":"7:30 PM", "mass_location":"", "mass_description": "Blah1"
} ] ,
"mass_info2":  [ { "mass_id":7781,  "mass_date":"6/10/2019", "mass_time":"7:30 PM", "mass_location":"1234 some place Los Angeles",  "mass_description": "Blah2"
} ] ,
"mass_info3":
[ { "mass_id":7783,  "mass_date":"5/21/2019",  "mass_time":"7:30 PM",  "mass_location":"",  "mass_description": "blah3"
} ] ,
"mass_info4":
[ { "mass_id":1115,  "mass_date":"4/5/2019", "mass_time":"2:30 PM", "mass_location":"4050 Mission Ave, Oceanside, CA 92057",  "mass_description": "blah4"
} ]
}
"""

struct MassInfoObject: Codable {
    var mass_id: Int
    var mass_date: String?
    var mass_time: String?
    var mass_location: String?
    var mass_description: String?
}

let data = str.data(using: .utf8)!

let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: [[String: Any]]]

let jsonArray = json!.values.map { $0 }

let cleanedJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArray, options: [])

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let items = try decoder.decode([[MassInfoObject]].self, from: cleanedJson)
```

The first steps are to convert the json to something that can be parsed easily. Because now MassInfoObject conforms to `Codable`, you can use a simple JSONDecoder to decode an array of objects, this is just one line of code.

Also, in your networking code you are calling an async task, but your are returning immediately, that's not going to work. When you return from the `getJson` function, you don't have the results yet. The easiest thing to do is use a closure that you can call with the results:

In your networking code it would look as such:

```
func getjson(handler: @escaping ([MassInfoObject]?)->()) {
  let urlPath = "http://myclassinfo.com/dev/json.php"
  let url = URL(string: urlPath)
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
     print("Task completed")

     guard let data = data && error == nil else {
        //print(error?.localizedDescription)
        return
     }
     do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: [[String: Any]]]
        let jsonArray = json!.values.map { $0 }
        let cleanedJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArray, options: [])
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let items = try decoder.decode([[MassInfoObject]].self, from: cleanedJson).compactMap { $0 }

        handler(items)

     } catch let parseError as NSError {
        print("JSON Error \(parseError.localizedDescription)")
        handler(nil)
     }
   }

   task.resume()
}
```

If you have json that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "mass_description": "Blah1", 
    "mass_date": "5/1/2019", 
    "mass_location": "", 
    "mass_time": "7:30 PM", 
    "mass_id": 7780
}, 
{
    "mass_description": "blah2", 
    "mass_date": "6/10/2019", 
    "mass_location": "1234 some place Los Angeles", 
    "mass_time": "7:30 PM", 
    "mass_id": 7781
}, 
{
    "mass_description": "blah3", 
    "mass_date": "5/21/2019", 
    "mass_location": "", 
    "mass_time": "7:30 PM", 
    "mass_id": 7783
}, 
{
    "mass_description": "blah4", 
    "mass_date": "4/5/2019", 
    "mass_location": "4050 Mission Ave, Oceanside, CA 92057", 
    "mass_time": "2:30 PM", 
    "mass_id": 1115
}
]
```

You could easily decode this:

```
let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([MassInfoObject].self, data)
```

Comment: Thank Marcel, I have compile error on line handler(items) the error message is Cannot convert value of type '[[MassInfoObject]]' to expected argument type '[MassInfoObject]?'  Should I have handler.append(items)

Comment: I updated the code, needed to flatten the response still. At the moment it's still not very elegant (as in, not at all). It would be a lot nicer if you have control over the json formatting.

Comment: Thank Marcel, if you would change the json, what would you change?

Comment: @JohnMiky As you certainly know that the JSON is widely about ***mass*** I recommend to remove the redundant information for example `"description": "Blah1", "date": "5/1/2019","location": "","time": "7:30 PM","id": 7780},`. Then you can declare the struct members conforming to the naming convention getting rid of the underscore characters.

Comment: Thank Marcel, Vadian I changed the json and use ```let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([MassInfoObject].self, data)``` it works perfectly .  I appreciate for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thank Marcel, and everyone who helped me.  Here is the code that I used

```
struct MassObj:Decodable{
    var mass_id:Int
    var mass_date: String
    var mass_time:String
    var mass_location:String
    var mass_description:String
}

func getJsonArray2() {

        let urlPath = "http://myclassinfo.com/dev/json.php"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else {return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
        {
            data, response, error in
            print("Task completed")

            guard data != nil && error == nil else {
                //print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            do{
                var massArray = [MassObj]()
                massArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([MassObj].self, from:data!)

                for object in massArray {
                    print("\(object.mass_id) == \(object.mass_date) == \(object.mass_description)")
                }

            }catch let jerr {
                print(jerr)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

================
and the json is

```
[
{
    "mass_description": "Blah1", 
    "mass_date": "5/1/2019", 
    "mass_location": "", 
    "mass_time": "7:30 PM", 
    "mass_id": 7780
}, 
{
    "mass_description": "blah2", 
    "mass_date": "6/10/2019", 
    "mass_location": "1234 some place Los Angeles", 
    "mass_time": "7:30 PM", 
    "mass_id": 7781
}, 
{
    "mass_description": "blah3", 
    "mass_date": "5/21/2019", 
    "mass_location": "", 
    "mass_time": "7:30 PM", 
    "mass_id": 7783
}, 
{
    "mass_description": "blah4", 
    "mass_date": "4/5/2019", 
    "mass_location": "4050 Mission Ave, Oceanside, CA 92057", 
    "mass_time": "2:30 PM", 
    "mass_id": 1115
}
]
```